# Menu Items Disappearing

Tags: php, menus

I'm running WP 3.5.1 and I've a menu with about 100 items. When I add new items to the menu older ones disappear.

I'm not running Suhosin or similar stuff. What can be the cause?

Note: I'm on a dedicated server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*The following has worked for some users with similar problem:*

Try to increase the value of the `max_input_vars` variable in `php.ini`. This variable was introduced in PHP version `5.3.9` and has the default value of `1000`.

You can read more about it in the PHP documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

```
max_input_vars  1000    PHP_INI_PERDIR  Available since PHP 5.3.9.
```

> How many input variables may be accepted (limit is applied to $_GET,
>   $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal separately). Use of this directive
>   mitigates the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash
>   collisions.

You could try to increase it to `1500` or `2000`.

### Estimate:

Using the data below, we can try to estimate how many POST variables we are sending, given a certain number of menu items, when we press the `Save Menu` button

[image: save]

It seems to be:

```
"number of POST variables" = 11 * "number of menu items" + 9
```

which is equivalent to the line:

```
y=11x+9
```

Then we can build the following table:

[image: table]

In your case, we see that if you need to save `100` menu items, you need to send `1109` POST variables, so your `max_input_vars` must be at least `1109`.

Similarly when we add items to the menu (via Ajax POST)

[image: add]

we get

```
"number of POST variables" = 10 * "number of menu items" + 3
```

which is the line:

```
y=10x+3
```

The corresponding data table is:

[image: table]

When we add `10` menu items, we send `103` POST variables.

### Data:

Just to show you the amount of `$_POST` data when I save my menu with only `5` items:

```
Array
(
    [menu-name] => simple_menu
    [save_menu] => Save Menu
    [closedpostboxesnonce] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [meta-box-order-nonce] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [update-nav-menu-nonce] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [_wp_http_referer] => /dev/wp-admin/nav-menus.php
    [action] => update
    [menu] => 58
    [menu-item-title] => Array
        (
            [1135] => home
            [1131] => page1
            [1130] => page2
            [1132] => page3
            [1133] => page4
        )

    [menu-item-attr-title] => Array
        (
            [1135] => 
            [1131] => 
            [1130] => 
            [1132] => 
            [1133] => 
        )

    [menu-item-classes] => Array
        (
            [1135] => 
            [1131] => 
            [1130] => 
            [1132] => 
            [1133] => 
        )

    [menu-item-xfn] => Array
        (
            [1135] => 
            [1131] => 
            [1130] => 
            [1132] => 
            [1133] => 
        )

    [menu-item-description] => Array
        (
            [1135] => 
            [1131] => 
            [1130] => 
            [1132] => 
            [1133] => 
        )

    [menu-item-db-id] => Array
        (
            [1135] => 1135
            [1131] => 1131
            [1130] => 1130
            [1132] => 1132
            [1133] => 1133
        )

    [menu-item-object-id] => Array
        (
            [1135] => 477
            [1131] => 1020
            [1130] => 1028
            [1132] => 791
            [1133] => 603
        )

    [menu-item-object] => Array
        (
            [1135] => page
            [1131] => page
            [1130] => page
            [1132] => page
            [1133] => page
        )

    [menu-item-parent-id] => Array
        (
            [1135] => 0
            [1131] => 0
            [1130] => 1131
            [1132] => 1131
            [1133] => 0
        )

    [menu-item-position] => Array
        (
            [1135] => 1
            [1131] => 2
            [1130] => 3
            [1132] => 4
            [1133] => 5
        )

    [menu-item-type] => Array
        (
            [1135] => post_type
            [1131] => post_type
            [1130] => post_type
            [1132] => post_type
            [1133] => post_type
        )

    [menu-locations] => Array
        (
            [primary] => 0
        )

)
```

When I add `3` items to them menu, the `POST` data is:

```
Array
(
    [action] => add-menu-item
    [menu] => 58
    [menu-settings-column-nonce] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [menu-item] => Array
        (
            [-56] => Array
                (
                    [menu-item-object-id] => 1728
                    [menu-item-db-id] => 0
                    [menu-item-object] => page
                    [menu-item-parent-id] => 0
                    [menu-item-type] => post_type
                    [menu-item-title] => Page 1
                    [menu-item-url] => http://example.com/page1/
                    [menu-item-target] => 
                    [menu-item-classes] => 
                    [menu-item-xfn] => 
                )

            [-57] => Array
                (
                    [menu-item-object-id] => 1724
                    [menu-item-db-id] => 0
                    [menu-item-object] => page
                    [menu-item-parent-id] => 0
                    [menu-item-type] => post_type
                    [menu-item-title] => Page 3
                    [menu-item-url] => http://example.com/page2/
                    [menu-item-target] => 
                    [menu-item-classes] => 
                    [menu-item-xfn] => 
                )

            [-59] => Array
                (
                    [menu-item-object-id] => 1658
                    [menu-item-db-id] => 0
                    [menu-item-object] => page
                    [menu-item-parent-id] => 0
                    [menu-item-type] => post_type
                    [menu-item-title] => Page 3
                    [menu-item-url] => http://example.com/page3/
                    [menu-item-target] => 
                    [menu-item-classes] => 
                    [menu-item-xfn] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Is it worth trying this if your [menu items for all menus are randomly being deleted on their own](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145811/menu-items-all-menus-being-deleted-randomly-on-their-own) would you say?

Comment: Setting our `max_input_vars` to 2000 didn't resolve the issue for us and we only have about 15 menu items.