# Images Missing from built in WP Gallery

Tags: gallery, limit

My wife has a wordpress 3.9.2 site that has a ton of images spread across many galleries. Many of those galleries though, have hundreds of images. This is partly managed by the Paginated Effects Gallery plugin, which breaks the galleries up into 15 image pages. On one particular [gallery page](http://rainbowbrite.org/fans/), which has more images than any other, after a recent update she has noticed that if more images are added to the gallery they do not always show up.

Note: This is *NOT* using NextGEN gallery (and she would prefer not to switch to it).

If we manually enter the Database IDs of the images into the [gallery ...] shortcode all of them will show up on the rendered page but nothing after image 995 will show up in the visual editor. It is not a specific image as if I move images to be before the current image #995 it just pushes everything past the new 995 out of the visual editor view. Though they stay in the shortcode and remain visible on the rendered page.

However, if we use the visual editor to add images, it works initially. Images after 995 show up on the rendered page and the editor. But, if we go back and add more, all those previously after 995 are replaced with the new ones, including if you look in the text view at the numbers in the gallery shortcode.

So, clearly, if it's in the gallery shortcode it will show up on the rendered page no matter what. But the visual editor seems to not be able to show or add anything past 995 without overwriting the images previously in those spots.

Unfortunately, the only real way to get those database IDs is with the visual editor :(

I have not been able to find anything that says there is a max number of images you can have in one gallery. If it was right at 1000 I would just assume it was a hard limit. But 995 seems very weird.

We have disabled *ALL* plugins, restored from old DB backups, created a new page and copied that gallery's code into it... all with the same result.

Anyone have an idea of what could be going on here?

NOTE: This problem STILL occurs regardless of the Paginated Effects Gallery plugin being enabled or not. I have already confirmed it still happens without ANY plugins enabled.

Comment: IF you can enable debuggin in your wp-config with this line: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`. The problem could be related to the massive amount of images you are trying to load. Also, check the site's error logs.

Comment: Good Call. I tried, but it generated no errors (I also enabled WP_DEBUG_LOG).

Comment: Any Javascript Errors during this process?

Comment: You would think. But no :(

Comment: Can you add the code generated automatically for the shorcodes? The one that is in the HTML tab of the editor.

Comment: Just the usual: [gallery link="file" ids="1,2,3,4,5..."] 
... being up through 995 pictures (and no the links aren't actually sequential).

Comment: @AdamHaile, did you have any luck? I'm currently uploading a lot of files to test this, it could be a bug.

Comment: Sadly no. I'm evaluating other gallery plugins to work around it, but still no go on the built in. Thanks for testing :)

Comment: @AdamHaile, it's me again, images are still uploading but I found a lot of error while uploading images with special characters (ñ, á, é). I'll update you when the loading is finished

Comment: Except for the images with special characters, the rest loaded just fine, above 1000 images. Did you check your browser's console?

Comment: Checked the console and no messages. However, I tried this on a clean Wordpress 3.9.2 install. I uploaded 1200 images and created a gallery from all of them. Again, just as with the other site, it loaded them all initially. But after trying to add more images, it lost everything after image 995, even those that worked on the first add. If you go back to your gallery and try to add a few more, does it still work?

Comment: Anything in the webserver's logs? I wonder if this could be related to restrictions to the GET or POST data. Can you see any large chunks of data being sent (via ajax?) while you do this? This reminds me a little bit of the elusive problem with the [disappearing nav-menu items](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96587/menu-items-disappearing). Just a thought ... since it's not easy to test your claim ;-)

Comment: @AdamHaile, have you tried asking you hosting? They tend to limit the amount of files that can be in each directory. I think you should see some kind of error in the logs, but if I were you I would ask, just to be sure.

Comment: Checked both... nothing in the logs (I enabled ALL the debugging everywhere I could). And no directory limits. I have thousands of images in several folders.

Comment: ps: I just want to mention that the default value of [`max-input-vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) is `1000`.

Comment: Hmmm... I have no idea how it posts the values, but on both my servers that is defaulting to 1000. So if there are 5 other vars it sends, then 995 makes total sense. Especially that it would just drop the last values. Will test tonight.

Comment: @birgire : `max-input-vars` could be a lead, but I do not see any request that adds one more variable for each new image added to a gallery. No GET or POST request is even sent to create or modify the `[gallery]` shortcode with the visual editor.

Comment: Looks like you are correct. I tried upping that variable and the same 995 was still the limit. Oh well...

Comment: ok, it was a long shot, but it's always good to have something to rule out ;-)

Comment: I believe the issue might be wordpress size restrictions. Please check in settings: 

Upload Settings
Site upload space: Limit total size of files uploaded to [xxx]MB. 

This could be the issue. Also please check your hosting provider disk size. If this solves your issue I'll write it as an answer.

Comment: Are images present in uploads folder ?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? This may be a limitation to protect against too many DOM elements or something. Which browser are you using now?

Comment: Yes, I have tried multiple browsers. IE, Firefox and Chrome (my default). 

All images are being uploaded.

Check the OP - It's not a size restriction. The files upload fine. I can manually edit the gallery shortcode and it works. The visual editor just won't add them past 995.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still never found a solution that actually fixed the problem.
In the end, my work-around was to break each gallery into sub-galleries of less than 200 images and then use the  tag to paginate the main page.

This avoided the 995 file limitation as well as vastly improved performance since it only ever tried to load a couple hundred images.

Not ideal, but probably best.

Would still be nice if I knew why it broke in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

You have a limit inside an script  and you should change some values to adapt your needs:

```
jQuery....
//user settings
var thumbsPerPage = 15;
var maxPaginatedLinks = 200;
var hideEffect = "drop";
var showEffect = "drop";
var effectSpeed = "slow";
var count = 1;  
//handles multiple galleries on page
var galleryCount = $( "[id^=gallery-]" ).each( function()
var galleryId = "#" + $( this ).attr( "id" ) + " ";
```

Comment: That's part of the Paginated Effects Gallery plugin and the problem still happens with that plugin disabled.

Answer (score 0):

There are two plausible answers.

1. There is a good chance this is a restriction on the wordpress site settings.

   In multisite this is in:

   > Network -> Settings:
   >
   > **Upload Settings**
   >
   > Site upload space: [checkbox] Limit total size of files uploaded to
   >   [xxx]MB. Default is 50MB.

   Unchecking this or increasing the limit should solve the issue. The side affect of this setting is it would bump off the images which was one of your side effects.
2. Less likely but check with your hosting provider about your disk space. In that case you would not get any wordpress errors, but the file would not get written to disk if it is out of space. They should have an admin login where you can check your disk space, or just contact them and ask.